# Getting NullPointerException for getActionBar after Updating SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I'm using Android Studio, everything was going good until I update my `SDK` to API level 21 and also update Support Library.
Before Updating I was not getting `NullPointerException` but after updating `SDK` getting `NullPointerException` for `getActionBar()`at runtime without changing any single line of code or anything.
Please help me, **one more thing I'm beginner in using Android Studio.**

Log:

```
 07-09 13:46:12.138  25209-25209/com.oi.abc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.oi.abc/com.oi.abc.HomeScreenActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.oi.abc.NavigationDrawerExpandableListviewClass.initializeScreen(NavigationDrawerExpandableListviewClass.java:148)
            at com.oi.abc.NavigationDrawerExpandableListviewClass.onCreate(NavigationDrawerExpandableListviewClass.java:71)
            at com.oi.abc.HomeScreenActivity.onCreate(HomeScreenActivity.java:47)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you include the exception stack too.

Comment: Please provide logcat error

Comment: Can you post your *onCreate()*  method? and from which class you extend your activity

Comment: what is theme you have given for your activity? and which class you are extending ?

Answer (score 0):

I encoutner such kind of problems but without seeing your code i can't say much.Here 2 ways which might happen and there are i guess no other ways.First is that after update you now have app.v7.widget.ActionBar and you have app.widget.Actionbar,so here how it goes,if your actionable is imported as FIRST one i mentioned above,use this

```
getSupportActionBar()
```

however if its imported the second one you should uses only

```
getActionBar()
```

Mostly your might get null pointer as i might guess the imported actionable is wrong one and you might want to uses my first option of it.Thats the new revision of supports library and sdks of android unfortunately i did encouter couple times to this issue.